# Please explain me how to control a Table View in Cocoa?

Tags: xcode4, tableview, datasource, cell

I search Google to find a good answer but the most tutorials are shown in previous Xcode Versions... 
Also, I don't want to drag-n-drop cells from the Interface Builder, but to control the Table View programmatically *(from an NSObject subclass file)*.

#### What I currently do is this:

1. Create a file named tableController.h that is a subclass of NSObject.
2. I create an NSObject Object in my Nib File *(and set it as a subclass of tableController)*.
3. I drag a Table View to my window.
4. I CTRL+Drag from the Table View to my tableController.h so to create the outlet "tableView"

5. I create these functions in the interface file:

```
-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)cocoaTV;
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)cocoaTV:objectValueForTableCollumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableCollumn row:(int)row;
```

6. I implement the functions like this:

```
-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)cocoaTV{
    return 5;
}
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)cocoaTV:objectValueForTableCollumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableCollumn row:(int)row{
    NSArray *tvArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    NSString *v = [tvArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return v;
}
```

Then I CTRL+Drag from the Object in the Interface Builder to the Table View to set the dataSource and to set it as delegate.

When I build and Run the App it shows that it has created the 5 Rows but in every cell in every column it says "Table View Cell".

**Any help would be appreciated....**

Comment: Not fixing your problem, but you leak the array you're creating. You should use `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)cocoaTV:objectValueForTableCollumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableCollumn row:(int)row` is wrong.. i'm not sure how it compiles, to be honest (unless there was an error copy/pasting it). the method should look like:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSArray *tvArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    NSString *v = [tvArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return v;
}
```

Comment: So, the table we apply is the tableView after the _(NSTableView *)_ statement and the column is the tableColumn after the _(NSTableColumn)_? I need somebody to explain the methods....

Comment: that's right, yep - and row is the row of the table. you don't need to worry about the tableColumn unless you have multiple columns. if you do have multiple columns, then be sure to set the NSTableColumn identifier in Interface Builder so you can figure out which column you're being asked to return the objectValue for.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for explaining.... However, for some reason, it still says "Table View Cell" in every Row and Column

Comment: hmm :( in interface builder, does the Table Column contain a "Text Field Cell"? if not, try dragging out a Text Field Cell on top of whatever cell is there.

Comment: I have a problem with multiple columns. I edit the Identifier (_myColumn_) and set the methods to this:                                               - (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)myColumn row:(NSInteger)row;                             It doesn't show anything.... What am I doing wrong?